# Django keep data after validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need store the values in input form after Djando validations.How can I do that? Still after validation the inputs will be empty. Laravel has function old() for that, but Django doesnt know this function. User have to fill the input once again and this is the problem. Some idea? Thanks for all help

I have this for in my template in Django /python3/:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ register_form }}
<button type="submit" class="mt-3 btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

This is my form class:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

     username = forms.CharField(

         label='Uživatelské jméno',
         label_suffix='',
         required=False,
         widget=forms.TextInput(
             attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

     )

     email = forms.EmailField(

         label='E-mail',
         label_suffix='',
         required=False,
         widget=forms.TextInput(
             attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'email'}),

     )
```

Answer (score 0):

In django, the logic is handled by **view layer**, so if you want to keep the value, simply send it *back* to template after validation process (usually you want it when your validation has not been passed).

Let's say you are using function based views, so you can use:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
        # do your validation
        if <validation_passed>:
            return redirect('your_success_url')
    else:
        my_form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, '<your_template_name>', {'register_form':my_form})
```

you can also use `myform = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)` if you want to keep it in one line.

Now, since the `request.POST` include the data that user had filled in, and you are sending back the form with those data, you will have them on your form.

Comment: Pedram Parsian : Change my code, look above .... still not working

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are using `RegisterForm()` when the form is not valid. It should be `RegisterForm(request.POST)`.